# Object has property value that is different than value returned when calling property

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of objects rendered via a React Native FlatList. Each item in the list renders a custom component. Each object has a property called `unreadMessageCount` that returns a number. If that number is greater than 0, then a boolean flag is passed to my custom component that render a small badge indicating there are unread messages if that boolean is true. When the user taps on the custom component the list of messages are displayed, and all messages (conversation) is marked as read. The array of object is updated and the Flatlist re-renders the new list (confirmed).

Now for the bizarre part. In the render item function, where I determine if the `unreadMessageCount` is greater than 0, the object itself has the correct value for the property, but calling the property returns the previous value. For example, if I `console.log(object)` I can inspect the object's `unreadMessageCount` property and I see the correct 0 value, however in the next line of code if `console.log(object.unreadMessageCount)` it does not show the correct value of 0, rather it displays the previous value. How is that even possible?

I have also tried doing the `unreadMessageCount > 0` logic in the custom component as well with the same result.

```
renderItem({item}) {
  console.log('item', item); //  { unreadMessageCount: 0, ... }
  console.log('item.unreadMessageCount', item.unreadMessageCount);  // 1

  return (
    <ConversationCard
      conversation={item}
      showUnreadBadge={item.unreadMessageCount > 0}
    />
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.conversations}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.url}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are either mutating data somewhere or you substitute FlatList data in a wrong way (do I understand it correctly that you are using the same FlatList to display list of conversations and list of messages?)

Reason why your two console.logs behave different is that the first one is logging the object, and if you mutate this object after logging and then inspect it, you will see the new data inside the object, not the one that was there at the time of logging it. You can confirm it by substituting this `console.log('item', item)` for this `console.log('item', JSON.stringify(item))`

So, make sure you are not mutating your data anywhere and make use of `extraData` prop of FlatList https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using the FlatList for only the rendering the array of conversation objects. Each ConversationCard component opens a full screen Overlay when tapped that renders a separate FlatList within it. As far as mutating the data, I also suspected that too, but I don't think I am, but maybe I'm missing something. My reducer for getting the array of conversations (initially and when updates are made, i.e. marking a conversation as read) looks like this:

`
return {
  ...state,
  conversations: action.payload.conversations,
}
`

Answer (score 0):

I think the conversation objects are being mutated by a third party library. I may need to rethink how I am storing and updating this information in my reducer...